# Finding the Kth Closest Elements to the median using quickselect

Tags: python, algorithm

given an array containing both negative and positive values, how could I find the kth closest elements to the median? I have a quickselect method that finds the median of the array. Then I loop through the original array and create another array `diff` where I keep the absolute value of each element in the array minus the median (`abs(a[i]-median)`). However, I am lost on how to modify my quickselect and partition to achieve this. This is what I have at the moment.

finding the value in the middle of array `a`:

```
midpoint=int(len(a)/2)
median=quickSelect(a,0,len(a)-1,midpoint)
```

where `quickSelect` looks like this:

```
def quickSelect(array,start,end,k):

    if start>=end:
        return array[k]

    value=partition(array,start,end)

    if value>k:
        return quickSelect(array,start,value-1,k)
    else:
       return quickSelect(array,value+1,end,k)
```

and the `partition` method looks like this:

```
def partition(array,start,end):
    x=start-1
    #pivot is the last element at each iteration
    pivot=array[end]

    for i in range(start,end):
        if array[i]<=pivot:
            x+=1
            array[x],array[i]=array[i],array[x]        
    array[x+1],array[end]=array[end],array[x+1]
    return x+1
```

then I store the absolute value of the differences:

```
diff=[None]*len(a)     
for x in range(len(a)):
    diff[x]=abs(a[x]-median)
```

At this point is where I don't know what modifications to make to the new quickselect and partition functions that I used to find the median of the array.

an example output having an array `[10, 4, 2,15, 18]` and `k=2` would be `4,15`

EDIT:
I think I have come closer to the solution but my new code fails when the array size is larger. I have created the array `diff` without the absolute value (`diff[x]=a[x]-median`)

then I switch the position of the value in the middle with 0 (`diff[midpoint],diff[0]=diff[0],diff[midpoint]`) since nothing is less than the absolute value of the value at the middle minus the value itself.

Then I created a `quickSelectKClosest` function that calls the `partitionAbsoluteValue` method, which considers absolute values.

`quickSelectKClosest`:

```
    def quickSelectKClosest(array,start,end,k):

        if start>=end:
            return array[k]

        value=partitionAbsoluteValue(array,start,end)

        if value>k:
            return quickSelectKClosest(array,start,value-1,k)
        else:
            return quickSelectKClosest(array,value+1,end,k)
```

`partitionAbsoluteValue`:

```
def partitionAbsoluteValue(array,start,end):
    x=start-1
    pivot=array[end]

    for i in range(start,end):
        if abs(array[i])<=abs(pivot):
            x+=1
            array[x],array[i]=array[i],array[x]        
    array[x+1],array[end]=array[end],array[x+1]

    return x+1
```

and back in `main` i call `quickSelectKClosest` like this:

`val=quickSelectKClosest(diff,1,len(diff)-1,1+k)`

with 1 as the start and `1+k` as the kth value (since value 0 is at `diff[0]`)

Then I find the position of the value returned by `quickSelectKClosest`:

`indexOfKthLargest=diff.index(val)`

and finally iterate through the `diff` array and add the value in the middle back:

```
for x in range(1,indexOfKthLargest+1):
    print(diff[x]+median)
```

But if I have an array: `[16, -23, 53, 19, -39, 99, 84, 95, 7, 6, 64, -79, 89, 43, 41]`

and `k=3`

The output is not entirely right:

```
The median was:  41 
The kth closest to the median are
43
53
19
```

I forgot to mention this but the values in the array are unique so they don't repeat.

Comment: how about `quickSelect(a,0,len(a)-1,midpoint-k)` and `quickSelect(a,0,len(a)-1,midpoint+k)`?

Comment: are you constrained to python 2 ?

Comment: @WalterTross I am not constrained to python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using quickselect, select the 2k elements (if n is even) or 2k + 1 elements (if n is odd) centred around the median, then use a two-index technique to select a sublist of length k. Initialise two indices `i` and `j` to the left and right of the median, and count `i` down or `j` up until the range from `i` to `j` includes the median and `k` other elements.

For this example, with `k = 2`:

```py
[16, -23, 53, 19, -39, 99, 84, 95, 7, 6, 64, -79, 89, 43, 41]
```

The 2k + 1 elements centred around the median are `mids = [16, 19, 41, 43, 53]`, in sorted order. The median itself is `mids[2]`.

- Initialise `i = 1` and `j = 3` for the two-index technique.
- `mids[j]` is closer to the median than `mids[i]`, so increment `j` to 4.
- `mids[j]` is still closer to the median than `mids[i]`, so increment `j` to 5.
- Now that `j - i - 2 >= k`, stop. The `k` closest numbers to the median are within the range:

  - Exclude the left boundary `i = 1`.
  - Exclude the median itself at index 2.
  - Include the value at index 3, which is 43.
  - Include the value at index 4, which is 53.

So the result is `[43, 53]`.